# Python error in list output due to integer error

Tags: python

Thanks to those who give me a solution earlier on.
However i need to utilise the split function for the solution as its part of the requirement stated. When i run this code, there is an error

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
7
8 for x in dob_list:
----> 9     age +=[year-int(x.split("-")[-1:])]
10 print(age)

### TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

```
dob_list = ['01-Jan-1990', '11-Aug-1995', '15-Apr-1982', '20-Mar-1988', '25-Nov-1976', '07-Dec-1965', 
            '18-Dec-1977', '25-May-1994', '09-Oct-1981', '19-Feb-1981']


year = 2021
age =[]

dob = []

for x in dob_list:
    age +=[year-int(x.split("-")[-1:])]

print(age)
```

Comment: you'd want `[-1]`, which takes the last element, rather than `[-1:]`, which takes a slice starting with the last element

Comment: Post the full traceback message, not a description of the error. We are used to them. You have a fairly complex expression. You could break it down and see what you get. For instance, `print(repr(x.split("-")[-1:]))`. Is that what you want to pass to `int()`?

Answer (score 1):

`x.split("-")[-1:]` actually gives you a list which contains only the last list item, since you are using a range (like `[-1:]`) instead of a number (like `[-1]`).

`x.split("-")[-1]`gives you the last list item (from `x.split("-")`) as a string.

Answer (score -1):

The number one debug tool in python is `print`. A line is failing? Print the stuff on the line before to see what you get.

```
dob_list = ['01-Jan-1990', '11-Aug-1995', '15-Apr-1982', '20-Mar-1988', '25-Nov-1976', '07-Dec-1965', 
            '18-Dec-1977', '25-May-1994', '09-Oct-1981', '19-Feb-1981']


year = 2021
age =[]

dob = []

for x in dob_list:
    print("next value", repr(x.split("-")[-1:]))
    age +=[year-int(x.split("-")[-1:])]
```

Running, I get

```
$ python3 test.py
next value ['1990']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/td/tmp/j/i.py", line 12, in <module>
    age +=[year-int(x.split("-")[-1:])]
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

That traceback is useful. I see the failing line and it tells me `int()` doesn't like lists. Looking backwards... yep, that was a list being passed in. Just get the final value instead.

```
age +=[year-int(x.split("-")[-1])]
```

Comment: Thanks ! so i just remove the : and it solve the problem :-)